# LGPLv3 app with an included ISCL license library?

Tags: licensing, lgpl

I have an application (or library) with an Lesser GPL v3 license. I'd like to use (and publish it with) an ISCL licensed library. Would this be ok?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISC license is quite simple:

> Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
>   purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
>   copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
>   (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISC_license))

It doesn't forbid you to sub-license the code or redistribute it under another license. You can thus redistribute along LGPL licensed work, as long as you make sure to preserve the original copyright note.

Answer (score 1):

ISC is [compatible](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html) to GPL (and as such, LGPL).